# Browser processing images

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload

I am having some problems with browsers displaying images correctly. Most of the browsers are affected except Chrome.

The problem here seems to be the caching problem of images. I am not very sure if this is the case, so I will tell you guys what I did.

My page allows users to upload their photos. So these uploaded photos will be saved into a folder. The user will then use the crop tool to crop their images to their preference, and saved them back to the same folder again. If they chose to use the same name, the image will be overwritten.

Here comes the problem. In Chrome, the browser will show the new cropped images, but not for the other browsers. If the image was renamed, then this won't happen either. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: add a new guid and append to the image filenames.

Comment: I think I found the solution to this. What I did was to add a random generated number at the back of the image. e.g image.png?321321.

Comment: haha thx. didn't see your comment while typing that message

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new guid at the end of the filenames as **`image.jpg?id=asdf`**

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name each time you save. You really *need* caching, but you don't want it to happen at the wrong times. Adding a random number will prevent browsers from caching images at all, prevent http.sys level caching, and prevent any edge caching you implement from working.